# How can I write XML which is divided into three horizontal columns and four vertical rows?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

How can I write xml which is divided into three horizontal columns and four vertical rows?

It should be divide into three columns while three columns further divided into four rows as per screenshot shown below.

How can I get views like attached image through XML?

[image]

For horizontal:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:background="#ffff">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/glassconsumed1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:layout_height="20.7dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/glassconsumed22"
            android:src="@drawable/icon2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:layout_height="20.7dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/glassconsumed32"
            android:src="@drawable/icon2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:layout_height="20.7dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

for Vertical

```
<LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/glassconsumed1"
            android:id="@+id/l2"
            android:background="#ffff">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/glassconsumed1"
            android:hint="   14/16"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="#8E8E8E"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/editTextvalue1" />
            <TextView

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editTextvalue1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="  Glasses"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="#8E8E8E"

                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/editTextvalue2" />
            <TextView

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editTextvalue2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Consumed"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="#8E8E8E"

                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/editTextvalue3" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Depends on the use case, you can use recyclerview with count 3 if data is dynamic or all 3 layouts are different or you can also use nested LinearLaout or Gridlayout. Do some research, it's not that difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set this type hope this can help you..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:weightSum="1">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".33"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#cccccc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="14/16" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#cccccc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Glasses" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#cccccc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Consumed" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".33"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#cccccc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="14/16" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#cccccc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Glasses" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#cccccc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Consumed" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".33"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#cccccc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="14/16" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#cccccc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Glasses" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#cccccc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Consumed" />

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Using this only images are coming text are not coming

Comment: vertical line is not appearing

Comment: for your provided image there is no any vertical line

Comment: In image after image and text vertical lines are present. No problem i have added some code now it is appearing Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<Linear
    orientation="vertical"
        <Linear
            orientation=horizontal
                <Linear
                    orientation=vertical
                    <textview>
                    <imageview>
                    <textview>
                    <Textview>
                </linear>
                <Linear
                    orientation=vertical
                    <textview>
                    <imageview>
                    <textview>
                    <Textview>
                </linear>
                <Linear
                    orientation=vertical
                    <textview>
                    <imageview>
                    <textview>
                    <Textview>
                </linear>
        </Linear>
</linear>
```

you can go like this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridLayout or TableLayout
See these examples: [TableLayout](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_table_layout.htm), [GridLayout](https://inducesmile.com/android-tutorials-for-nigerian-developer/understanding-grid-layout-in-android/)